# Python3 parsing and catching multiple optional arguments in a line

Tags: regex, python-3.x, parsing

I'm currently parsing files concerning movies.
Here is an example of the language file :

```
"!Next?" (1994)                     Italian
"#1 Single" (2006)                  English
"#15SecondScare" (2015)                 English
"#15SecondScare" (2015) {Because We Don't Want You to Fall Asleep 
 (#1.3)}    English
"#15SecondScare" (2015) {Coming and Going (#1.11)}  English
"#Adulthood" (????)                 English
"#Adulting" (2016/I)                    English
```

How can I catch the name, the year, saison and episode if it's a tv-show and the language of each line ? 
There is some arguments that are not always there (like which episode it is) ?

This is what I tried : 

   `for line in file:
        print(re.findall('"(.*)"', line))           #name
        print(re.findall(r"\D(\d{4})\D",line))      #year`

I'm already having trouble with years, because it catches the episode number.
Is doing multiple pattern the way to go ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying, I think it was no use to write what I wrote because I fell like I'm missing something...
I'll edit thanks !

Comment: Season looks optional, is it ?

Comment: When it contains `{}`it must be a show, and the brackets are :  `{Episode name (#SeasonNumber,episodeNumber)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like

```
import re

string = """
"!Next?" (1994)                     Italian
"#1 Single" (2006)                  English
"#15SecondScare" (2015)                 English
"#15SecondScare" (2015) {Because We Don't Want You to Fall Asleep 
 (#1.3)}    English
"#15SecondScare" (2015) {Coming and Going (#1.11)}  English
"#Adulthood" (????)                 English
"#Adulting" (2016/I)                    English
"""

rx = re.compile(r'''
            ^
            "(?P<name>[^"]+)"
            [^(]+\((?P<year>[^)]+)\)
            (?:[^\{^\n]+\{(?P<subtitle>[^}]+)\})?
            \s+(?P<language>[A-Z][a-z]*)
            $
            ''', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

movies = [(m.group('name'), m.group('year'), m.group('subtitle'), m.group('language'))
            for m in rx.finditer(string)]
print(movies)
# [('!Next?', '1994', None, 'Italian'), ('#1 Single', '2006', None, 'English'), ('#15SecondScare', '2015', None, 'English'), ('#15SecondScare', '2015', "Because We Don't Want You to Fall Asleep \n (#1.3)", 'English'), ('#15SecondScare', '2015', 'Coming and Going (#1.11)', 'English'), ('#Adulthood', '????', None, 'English'), ('#Adulting', '2016/I', None, 'English')]
```

See a demo of the [**matches on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/i8LDwE/1/).

---

A bit of explanation:

1. First, we define our regex pattern in *verbose* and *multiline* mode
2. We use the compiled pattern `rx` to iter over the found matches
3. We put the named group in a result tuple.
4. We end up having a *list of tuples*.

Comment: @user4725217: The pattern is compiled first and then iterated over (`finditer`). Makes the code more readable in my opinion. For further information have a look at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html

Comment: @user4725217: Have added a bit of explanation at the end of the answer as well.